# 12 volt input to 5 volt ouput of Arduino

Tags: arduino

I accidentally ended up supplying 12 v to the Arduino 5v output pin instead of the Vin pin. Does that mean that I can't use the 5v output pin anymore i.e. its fried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody can tell how much magic smoke is still in the device. You need a magic smoke detector (rarely also referred to as a "voltmeter"), hook one of its contacts up to the pin that should have 5 volts of smoke come out of it and the other to ground. If the detector says there are still 5v, you are probably in luck.

Comment: If you don't get 5Volts of magic smoke then the chances are the 12Volts you supplied has run and hidden else where in the Arduino.  You'll probably find out what else is dead when you try and use that feature.  Look on the bright side, you have learnt a valuable lesson, double check the wiring before turning the on switch.

Comment: Well its screwed now :/ The entire board is fried, nothing works :/ 
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Sandesh - If Bender's answer is the correct answer to your question, please mark is "accepted" (or else this question lingers forever). Thanks!